# Escape sequences in XML

Tags: java, jsp

I'm getting an Exception due to special characters when Xml is accessed by client [image]

Can any one help me...?

Comment: Can you paste your XML here (or the offending fragment) ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Here is My XML Code:`<MeterReadings>
  <Reading>
    <METER_NO>/-+'&*ÏÃ·ÃÃÃÃÏÏââ¢<></METER_NO>
  </Reading>
  <Reading>
    <METER_NO>/-+'&*ÏÃ·ÃÃÃÃÏÏââ¢<></METER_NO>
  </Reading>
</MeterReadings>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the correct encoding, and make sure the XML document is created with the same encoding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="INSERT ENCODING HERE"?>
```

Comment: which encoding type is giving all special character support...?

Comment: Typically you should be fine with UTF-8. But you must make sure, the XML file is generated with the same encoding. How do you generate the XML?

Comment: I'm generated the xml with ASCII.Its working fine. Thanks a lot.,

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ensure the special characters are enclosed within `CDATA` sections:

```
<![CDATA[
some special characters here
]]>
```

Comment: My characters are not recognized by web browser. CDATA is not working. For Ex: While Debugging /-+'&*ÏÃ·ÃÃÃÃÏÏââ¢<> after that /-+'&*ÏÃ·ÃÃÃÃÏÏââ¢<>

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake in my case while opening/reading the XML i'm getting the error because   of three symbols. So need to replace the Character: `<>&` by EntityName: `&lt;&gt;&amp;`. Then only the parsing error will not be displayed.

[Click Here to see HTML Symbol Entities Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_symbols.asp)

[Click Here to Read XML Basic Generation](http://www.xmlnews.org/docs/xml-basics.html)

In other scenario instead symbols the Entity names need to be replaced then only parsing exception will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can include XML's special characters in XPL. XPL is structured exactly like XML but allows the special characters. The XPL to XML conversion utilities will take care of all the details for you. http://hll.nu